# AJAX requisição com dominio diferente

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, objetos, jsonp

minha Requisição

```
url="http://algumip:algumaporta/dowPDFNF?cChave="+chave

 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

erro que retorna:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, quando eu passo a url (gerada pela variavel url) direto no navagador, eu consigo o retorno certo. Veja imagem o retorno:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu preciso é pegar esse retorno para ter o download do pdf

```
{"pdf":"http:\\\\algumip\\download\\6a423e04e2c2dfd4a59f0001ec8bbf44b9a6a6d-nfe.pdf"}
```

Comment: Acredito que não é o caso, pois eu consigo chegar no outro dominio, problema está em ler o retorno "data" em success

Comment: O problema deve ser esse JSON.stringify, dá um console.log pra ver como está chegando o data.

Comment: Coloca um debugger dentro da função success.

    success: function (data) {
        debugger
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
Pra ver se está entrando no success.

Comment: @DanielleArrudatorres Fato, altere o título porque nesse caso não existe nenhuma relação com CORS e com o fato da requisção ser para outro domínio.

Comment: @DanielleArrudatorres você não pode fazer um post com o jsonp para outro domínio, a requisição não pode ser get?

Comment: @MayconF.Castro o  debugger me retorna "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: @LeandroAngelo vou alterar pra Get e testar

Comment: Não informa qual é o callback.

Comment: O tratamento do retorno também é diferente, implemente o jsonpCallback para analisar o retorno.

Comment: Mesmo com jsonp: "jsonpcallback",  dataType: "jsonp". Ainda tenho o retorno do erro : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77320/discussion-between-danielle-arruda-torres-and-leandro-angelo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente acrescentar o item  `async: false`, pois segundo a documentação, pedidos de `jsonp` a servidores remotos não funcionam se o modo *asynchronous* estiver ativo.

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.

```
$.ajax({ 
    async: false, 
    method: 'GET', 
    url: url, 
    contentType: "application/json", 
    jsonpCallback: minhafuncaocallback, 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    success: function (json) { 
        console.log(json); 
    }, 
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        console.log("AJAX ERRO" + jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown); 
    } 
});
```

É bom que esse pedido seja feito após a página ter sido totalmente carregada porque um pedido *synchronous* impede que o carregamento da página continue até que a resposta seja recebida daquele pedido o que pode diminuir a qualidade da experiência do usuário no seu site, se for o caso.